# NumPy or Dictionary?

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, dictionary, scikit-learn

I have to deal with a large data-set. I need to store term frequency of each sentence; which I can do either using a dictionary list or using NumPy array.

But, I will have to sort and append (in case the word already exists)- Which will be better in this case?

Comment: Why not try both and profile to find out?

Comment: I would also consider using a pandas `DataFrame`

Comment: If you plan on using a Tf-idf / KMeans or equivalent I would use NumPy arrays as they fit very well with scikit-learn. You might find your way with dictionnaries as well.

Comment: I have a text file containing 1M tweets; I need to calculate frequency of all the words inside my file and store it. I can do it using Numpy Array or a dictionary; but which will sort and search (to increment count) faster? I can try and calculate, but would be great if you could guide me  with the same.

Comment: I am also not sure on how I could initialize a matrix when I am not sure of the size!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Solution to the problem you are describing is a [scipy's sparse matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html).

A small example:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
docs = [["hello", "world", "hello"], ["goodbye", "cruel", "world"]]
indptr = [0]
indices = []
data = []
vocabulary = {}
for d in docs:
    for term in d:
        index = vocabulary.setdefault(term, len(vocabulary))
        indices.append(index)
        data.append(1)
    indptr.append(len(indices))

print csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), dtype=int).toarray()
```

Each sentence is row, and each term is a column.

#### One more tip - check out [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=2)
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This is the second second document.',
    'And the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]
vectorizer = vectorizer.fit(corpus)
print vectorizer.vocabulary_ 
#prints {u'this': 4, u'is': 2, u'the': 3, u'document': 0, u'first': 1}
X = vectorizer.transform(corpus)
    
print X.toarray()
#prints
 [[1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1]]
```

And now `X` is your document-term matrix (Note that X is `csr_matrix`). You can also use [TfidfTransformer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer) in case you want to tf-idf it.

Comment: CountVectorize seems interesting; let me explore it. Thanks!

Comment: @KushalShah Have fun with it..... notice that `transform` returns the data in `csr_matrix` anyway. One more thing from my experience - many of the tools you wish to apply on the data already exists in sklearn...I wasted many hours implementing stuff that already exists :-)

Comment: @KushalShah did you look at it? is that ok?

Comment: @KushalShah happy to help ;) feel free to accept and let other people know

Answer (score 1):

As you mention in the comments you don't know the size of the words/tweets matrix that you will eventually obtain, so that makes using an array a cumbersome solution.

It feels more natural to use a dictionary here, for the reasons you noted.
The keys of the dictionary will be the words in the tweets, and the values can be lists with (tweet_id, term_frequency) elements.

Eventually you might want to do something else (e.g. classification) with your term frequencies. I suspect this is why you want to use a numpy array from the start.
It should not be too hard to convert the dictionary to a numpy array afterwards though, if that is what you wish to do.

However note that this array is likely to be both very big (1M * number of words) and very sparse, which means it will contain mostly zeros. 
Because this numpy array will take a lot of memory to store a lot of zeros, you might want to look at a data structure that is more memory efficient to store sparse matrix (see scipy.sparse).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. My intended code is working well with dictionary; but was looking for ways to reduce time and space complexity.

Comment: If you are interested in reducing space complexity, you may also want to look at the hashing trick (see text.HashingVectorizer in scikit-learn). It has limitations (you can compute only counts of words and not tf-idf for instance), but it can save a lot of space by not storing the words themselves.

Comment: Yes, I did explore CountVectorize; let me try HashingVectorizer too. Thanks mate :)